# Transitive set - Example

Tags: elementary-set-theory

According to my notes, a set $A$ is called transitive if the elements of its elements are elements of $A$.
For example,  the set of natural numbers $\omega$ is a transitive set.

Also, if $n \in \omega$ then $n$ is a transitive set since $n=\{0,1,2, \dots, n-1 \}$ and if we take a $k \in n$ then $k=\{0,1,2, \dots, k-1 \}$.

Could you give me an example of an other transitive set? Or can a transitive set only contain natural numbers?

Comment: For example, $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\{\{\varnothing\}\}\}$ is transitive but $\{\{\varnothing\}\}$ is not an element of the set of natural numbers.

Comment: I see!!! $    $ @tetori

Answer (score 5):

If $A$ is a transitive set, then $\mathcal P(A)$ is a transitive set. Take now $\omega$ which is a transitive set, then $\mathcal P(\omega)$ is a transitive set, but its elements are sets of natural numbers, rather than just natural numbers.

Comment: For eaxmple, if we take $n=3$, we will have $n=\{0,1,2\}$ and so $\mathcal{P}n=\{ \varnothing, \{0\},\{1\},\{2\},\{0,1\},\{0,2\},\{1,2\},\{0,1,2\}\}$, right? and $\{m\}$, where $m \in \omega$ is not a natural number, right?
And because of the latter we conclude that $\mathcal{P}\omega$ is also not a transitive set?

Comment: @evinda $\cal P(\omega)$ and $\cal P(n)$ *are* transitive though. And $\{m\}$ is not a natural number unless $m=0$, in which case that is just $1$.

Comment: So, since having a transitive set of natural numbers means that for each element , its elements are contained in the set, means that if we take the subsets of these elements, the elements of the subsets will again be in the set?

Comment: That's right. Another way to state the transitivity constraint is that every element of $A$ is also a subset of $A$. In fact, if your transitive set contains only natural numbers, then it must itself be a natural number (or $\omega$), because any number in the set implies that all the numbers below it are also in the set.

Answer (score 3):

The ordinal numbers are exactly the transitive and $\in$-well-ordered sets. So every ordinal (including the natural numbers) is transitive. However, there is a strong claim in the reverse direction as well:

> For any set $x$, there is a transitive set that contains $x$.

In particular, since the intersection of transitive sets is transitive, the intersection of all such sets is a well-defined object called the transitive closure $TC(x)$, and it is always transitive and contains $x$. Thus, you can pick any non-ordinal and take its transitive closure, and this set will be transitive and contain non-ordinals. The smallest non-ordinal set is $\{1\}=\{\{\emptyset\}\}$, so $TC(\{1\})$, which can be explicitly constructed by just starting with $\{\{1\}\}$ and taking elements of elements (of elements...) and adding them to the set, produces a non-ordinal transitive set.

$$TC(\{1\})=\{\{1\},1,0\}=\{\{\{\emptyset\}\},\{\emptyset\},\emptyset\}$$

Here's a more complicated example:

\begin{align}
TC(\{1,2,\{2\}\})&=\{\{1,2,\{2\}\}\}\cup\{1,2,\{2\}\}\cup\{0,1,2\}\cup\{0,1\}\cup\{0\}\cup\emptyset\\
&=\{\{1,2,\{2\}\},\{2\},2,1,0\}
\end{align}

Comment: So does this mean that if we find a subset of a set that is not transitive then neither the set will be transitive? Or have I uderstood it wrong? :/

Comment: A subset of a transitive set can be non-transitive, and a subset of a non-transitive set can be transitive (for example $\emptyset\subset A$ is transitive). What I mean by the construction is that you start with $A=\{x\}$, then you append the union of the elements in $A$ to get $A\cup\bigcup A$, and then the union of that, $A\cup\bigcup A\cup\bigcup\bigcup A$, and so on. For finite sets you'll eventually hit empty set rock bottom and you can stop, for infinite sets you will have to do it $\omega$ times then stop.

Comment: In the example above, you get $A=\{\{1\}\}$, $\bigcup A=\{1\}$, $\bigcup\bigcup A=1$, $\bigcup\bigcup\bigcup A=\emptyset$, so you union all these together to get $\{\{1\},1,\emptyset\}$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro for infinite $A$ how we prove that we need $\omega$ to build $ TC (A) $ ?

Comment: @A.A.Bueno We don't necessarily need $\omega$ steps; but we know that $\omega$ steps is sufficient for any set $A$. This is because if $x\in y\in TC(A)$, then $y\in TC_k(A)$ for some $k$ (meaning the $k$-th stage of the construction), and so $x\in \bigcup TC_k(A)\subseteq TC_k(A)\cup\bigcup TC_k(A)=TC_{k+1}(A)\subseteq TC(A)$. Thus $TC(A)$ by the inductive construction is a transitive set.